# How big is the complement of stable locus $\operatorname{Bun}G$

Tags: vector-bundles, stacks, algebraic-stacks, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth projective curve, and $G$ a reductive group. Let $\operatorname{Bun}G$ be the stack of principal $G$ bundles on $\Sigma$ (with a fixed topological type).

> What is the codimension of the complement of the stable locus?

The complement is closed, so the codimension is $\geq 1$ if there exists a stable bundle. Is there any conditions that would guarantee the codimension is $\geq 2$?

Comment: For $G$ semi-simple simply connected, this is always the case. This is claimed (but not really proved) in Laszlo-Sorger, Ann. ENS 30, n°4  (1997), p. 523, (9.3).

Comment: @abx, it seems the quoted result says that strictly semistable bundles form a codimension $\geq 2$ subset. Do you know whether it is true the unstable bundles are also codimension $\geq 2$?